# Nonlocal pattern rather than C's native static with block scope

Tags: python

I create the such a snippet of code to test `nonlocal`:

```
def main():
    increased = 1
    def try_stat():
        nonlocal increased
        unchanged = 1
        unchanged += 1
        increased += 1
        print(f"unchanged = {unchanged} and increased = {increased}.") 

    for count in range(1, 4):
        print(f"Here comes iteration {count}")
        try_stat()
main()
```

Run it and get:

```
$ python loc_stat.py
Here comes iteration 1
unchanged = 2 and increased = 2.
Here comes iteration 2
unchanged = 2 and increased = 3.
Here comes iteration 3
unchanged = 2 and increased = 4.
```

Please notice that when declare a nonlocal variable, should tackle two steps:

1. declare increased = 1 in the outer scope
2. re-declare it as nonlocal.

Why not directly design the grammar as

```
def main():
    # increased = 1
    def try_stat():
        nonlocal increased = 1
```

C implements it using such a design of static with block scope

```
#include <stdio.h>
void try_stat(void);

int main(void)
{
    for (int count = 1; count <=3; count++)
    {
        printf("Here comes iteration %d:\n", count);
        try_stat();
    }

    return 0;
}

void try_stat(void)
{
    int unchanged = 1;
    static int increased = 1;

    printf("unchanged = %d and increased = %d\n", ++unchanged, ++increased);
}
```

Compiled it and come with

```
$ ./a.out
Here comes iteration 1:
unchanged = 2 and increased = 2
Here comes iteration 2:
unchanged = 2 and increased = 3
Here comes iteration 3:
unchanged = 2 and increased = 4
```

This solution seems more intuitive and Cpython is written in C,

What's the reason to choose current nonlocal pattern rather than C's native static with block scope?

Comment: They are not equivalent. `nonlocal` variable are visible outside of this block, unlike `static` variables.

Comment: See [PEP 3104](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/). `nonlocal` is not meant to be a `static` equivalent.

Comment: yes, what's the goodies for this design? @bipll

Comment: In fact, I think what you're up to is actually a class member variable. C is not an OO language and static variables are used to encapsulate persistent state between calls. Python has classes and properties of `self` for that.

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the short comment to answer. @bipll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both. :-)

They are not equivalent. `nonlocal` variables are visible outside of this block, unlike `static` ones.

In fact, I think what you're up to is actually a class member variable. C is not an OO language and `static` variables are used to encapsulate persistent state between calls. Python has classes and properties of `self` for that.